# Why isn't webdeploy sending across my static HTML file?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, webdeploy

I have an ASP.NET application that is split into two sub-projects: A static web front-end and an API layer. These are built and deployed separately.

We are using MSBUILD and Web Deploy to send the builds to our QA server and everything is being copied over properly except the static HTML. It is never included in the package.

Here is the simplified project structure:

```
/javascript
/img
/lib
bower.json
gruntfile.js
index.html
package.json
Web.csproj
Web.config
```

This is the command line doing the actual deploy:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe ^
    Project\Web.csproj ^
    /target:Rebuild ^
    /p:DeployIisAppPath=project-web ^
    /p:SiteAppName=project-web ^
    /p:Configuration=QA ^
    /p:OutputPath=package ^
    /p:DeployOnBuild=True ^
    /p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish ^
    /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://server:8172/msdeploy.axd ^
    /p:username=BUILDUSER ^
    /p:password=******** ^
    /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True ^
    /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSvc
```

After the deploy runs, this is what ends up on the target server:

```
/bin
/javascript
/img
/lib
bower.json
gruntfile.js
package.json
Web.config
```

As you can see, the `index.html` file is missing. All of the other assets - JavaScript, CSS, images - are present.

Tools in use:

- Visual Studio 2012
- Web Deploy 3
- ASP.NET 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a fair amount of digging, I figured out the issue. The file must not only be included in the project, but also must have its **Build Action** set to **Content**. It had been set to **None**.

[image: Screen shots showing the properties panel]